# Twitter API and "OR" request

Tags: api, twitter

Is that me or you can't make a "OR" request to the twitter API? :(

Comment: Which Twitter API? Search? Streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's search operators are confusing and annoying to use.

If you want to use 'OR', make sure to enclose the search terms in quotes (for phrases).

**Correct:**
"John is cheese" OR burger

**Incorrect:**
John is cheese OR burger

^^^this is interpreted as...
John AND is AND cheese OR burger

Comment: This syntax seems very sensible to me.

Comment: It makes sense logically, but you need to know that queries need to be technically correct, twitter's search isn't as forgiving or flexible as google's.